# In R, I am trying to make a for loop that will cycle through variable names and perform functions on them

Tags: r

I have variables that are named **team.1**, **team.2**, **team.3**, and so forth.

First of all, I would like to know how to go through each of these and assign a data frame to each one. So **team.1** would have data from one team, then **team.2** would have data from a second team. I am trying to do this for about 30 teams, so instead of typing the code out 30 times, is there a way to cycle through each with a counter or something similar?

I have tried things like

```
    vars = list(sprintf("team.x%s", 1:33)))
```

to create my variables, but then I have no luck assigning anything to them.

Along those same lines, I would like to be able to run a function I made for cleaning and sorting the individual data sets on all of them at once.

For this, I have tried a for loop

```
    for (j in 1:33) {
      assign(paste("team.",j, sep = ""), cleaning1(paste("team.",j, sep =""), j))
    }
```

where cleaning1 is my function, with two calls.

```
    cleaning1(team.1, 1)
```

This produces the error message

```
Error in who[, -1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

So obviously I am hoping the loop would count through my data sets, and also input my function calls and reassign my datasets with the newly cleaned data.

Is something like this possible? I am a complete newbie, so the more basic, the better.

Edit:

cleaning1:

```
cleaning1 = function (who, year) {
  who[,-1]
  who$SeasonEnd = rep(year, nrow(who))
  who = (who[-nrow(who),])
  who = tbl_df(who)
  for (i in 1:nrow(who)) {
    if ((str_sub(who$Team[i], -1)) == "*") {
      who$Playoffs[i] = 1
      } else {
      who$Playoffs[i] = 0
      }
     }
  who$Team = gsub("[[:punct:]]",'',who$Team)
  who = who[c(27:28,2:26)]
  return(who)
  }
```

This works just fine when I run it on the data sets I have compiled myself.

To run it though, I have to go through and reassign each data set, like this:

```
team.1 = cleaning1(team.1, 1)   

team.2 = cleaning1(team.2, 2)
```

So, I'm trying to find a way to automate that part of it.

Comment: Could you show `cleaning1`?   Also, I guess the `vars` would be either `vars = sprintf("team.x%s", 1:33)` or `vars <- as.list(sprintf("team.x%s", 1:33))`  It may be better to work with a single list of all the datasets rather than creating mutliple dataset objects in the global environment.

Comment: Alright, I added it to my original post. I guess that is etiquette, I am also new to Stack Overflow haha.

Comment: It is just to make your code reproducible so that others can run it  easily.  I noticed that there are other variables in the `Cleaning1` which is not clear to me.  A reproducible example is always preferred.

Comment: Please also check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok, I see. I'll try to put together something reproducible and post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem would be better solved by using a list of data frames instead of many variables containing one data frame each.

You do not say where you get your data from, so I am not sure how you would create the list. But assuming you have your data frames already stored in the variables `team.1` etc., you could generate the list with

```
team.list <- list(team.1, team.2, ...,team.33)
```

where the dots stand for the variables that I did not write explicitly (you will have to do that). This is tedious, of course, and could be simplified as follows

```
team.list <- do.call(list,mget(paste0("team.",1:33)))
```

The `paste0` command creates the variable names as strings, `mget` converts them to the actual objects, and `do.call` applies the `list` command to these objects.

Now that you have all your data in a list, it is much easier to apply a function on all of them. I am not quite sure how the `year` argument should be used, but from your example, I assume that it just runs from 1 to 33 (let me know, if this is not true and I'll change the code). So the following should work:

```
team.list.cleaned <- mapply(cleaning1,team.list,1:33)
```

It will go through all elements of `team.list` and `1:33` and apply the function `cleaning1` with the elements as its arguments. The result will again be a list containing the output of each call, i.e.,

```
list( cleaning1(team.list[[1]],1), cleaning1(team.list[[2]],2), ...)
```

Since you are now to R I strongly recommend that you read the help on the apply commands (`apply`, `lapply`, `tapply`, `mapply`). There are very useful and once you got used to them, you will use them all the time...

There is probably also a simple way to directly generate the list of data frames using `lapply`. As an example: if the data frames are read in from files and you have the file names stored in a character vector `file.names`, then something along the lines of

```
team.list <- lapply(file.names,read.table)
```

might work.

Comment: Thanks for the help! You are correct, 1:33 are the years, so year 1, year 2, year 3, etc... I played around with trying to use lists but I could never get anything to work properly that way. I kept getting an error message for incorrect dimensions. However, what you described above is exactly what I am trying to do, so I will go try what you posted above and try to figure out the apply commands!

Comment: So, I tried this, and I was successfully able to put my 33 data frames into a list. However, when I run the function on _team.list_ `team.list.cleaned <- mapply(cleaning1,team.list,1:33)`, instead of return a list of my 33 data frames, it returns a list of 891. The data frames have 27 variable each, 33 x 27 = 891, so it is taking my data out of the data frames and just returning a long list of all my variables. Any idea how to return in the form it was in after using `team.list <- do.call(list,mget(paste0("team.",1:33)))`?

Comment: Can you try `team.list.cleaned <- mapply(cleaning1,team.list,1:33,SIMPLIFY=FALSE)` instead?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment if you saw it. That worked, you are the best! Thank you.

Comment: You are most welcome. Just to be sure: it worked without `SIMPLIFY=FALSE`? If not, I should change my answer, so please let me know.